# NullPointer with playOrm 1.4.1 when persisting entity

Tags: orm, nosql, playorm

I have mapped entities in playORM and my project was running fine with my entities mapped the way they were. However, after installing playORM 1.4.1, the lastest version released in maven, I got the null pointer bellow.

I want to find the error, but have no clue of where to start looking.

Any hint?

INFO: found meta=User locally
2012-11-09 17:32:22,918 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper waitForNodesToBeUpToDate
INFO: LOOP until all nodes have same schema version OR timeout in 300000 milliseconds
2012-11-09 17:32:22,939 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Well, we did NOT find any column family=User to load in cassandra(from virt=User)
2012-11-09 17:32:22,939 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyVirt
INFO: Total time to LOAD column family meta from cassandra=21
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaEmbeddedSimple.translateToColumnImpl(MetaEmbeddedSimple.java:105)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaEmbeddedSimple.translateToColumn(MetaEmbeddedSimple.java:93)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle.translateToRow(MetaClassSingle.java:82)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerImpl.putImpl(BaseEntityManagerImpl.java:102)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerImpl.put(BaseEntityManagerImpl.java:68)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.UserDao.insertOrUpdateUser(UserDao.java:23)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.module.UserModule.persistData(UserModule.java:116)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.processor.mapred.SelectorReducer.reduce(SelectorReducer.java:60)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.processor.mapred.SelectorReducer.reduce(SelectorReducer.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:260)
17:32:22,946  WARN Thread-3 mapred.LocalJobRunner:298 - job_local_0001
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.processor.mapred.SelectorReducer.reduce(SelectorReducer.java:63)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.processor.mapred.SelectorReducer.reduce(SelectorReducer.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:260)
2012-11-09 17:32:27,237 com.s1mbi0se.dmp.processor.main.DmpProcessorRunner run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in release 1.4.2 which is available in Maven repo

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This is fixed in master branch and soon to be released. 11/27/12

The log formatting seems a bit off but this is the important part

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaEmbeddedSimple.translateToColumnImpl(MetaEmbeddedSimple.java:105)
```

line 105 finds this code...

```
    for(T val : toBeAdded) {
        byte[] name = formTheName(val);
        Column c = new Column();
        c.setName(name);

        row.getColumns().add(c);
    }
```

specifically line 105 is the first line so toBeAdded is null for some reason....looking at who called this method.

hmmm, it turns out ONE of your entities has a null list of something.  We need to add code in here so if your entity has a null list we create an empty one instead.  Can you file a ticket and link to this URL.  We can fix this one easily.

NOTE: I have a habit of every entity with a field like so

private List something;

I 100% always define it like this

private List something = new ArrayList();

That avoids Nullpointers all over the place which is why I missed this one :( :(.....anyways, we will fix to allow this null lists.

thanks,
Dean